# Error with include files core and highgui in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opencv

i am getting the following error, when i build my project,

```
   Fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/core/core_c.h: No such file or directory Similarly for highgui.
```

As i have installed OpenCV2.4.3 and its path is C:\opencv. I also have added these line in **include directories**

```
  C:opencv\include\opencv 
  C:opencv\include\opencv2
  C:\opencv\include
```

source code is:

```
// #include "stdafx.h"
   #include "cv.h"
   #include "highgui.h"

 int main() 
 {
         IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:\\prado.jpg",1);
         cvNamedWindow( "test", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
         cvShowImage( "test", img );
         cvWaitKey(0);
         cvReleaseImage( &img );
        return 0;
```

}
everything seems fine to me. i have removed everything in release mode. i am  Trying  debug mode only.

---

Configuration of Open CV which i have done is:
[image: include files]

Library files

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to read `How to build applications with OpenCV inside the Microsoft Visual Studio` 

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I did and it works fine:

Include the following path in include files:

1. `opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2\core`
2. `opencv\include\opencv2`
3. `opencv\include\opencv`
4. `opencv\build\include`

include the following path in library files;

1. `opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib`

Comment: Add this to you environment path Right Click My Computer -> properties -> advance -> path -> C:\OpenCV2.4.3\opencv\build\x86\vc9\bin;
Don't forget to add all the dependencies files at Project->Properties->Linker->Input

Comment: That's weird. I have .dll files under that folder.

Comment: you are using vs 2008 right? there suppose to be .dll files under the path I gave. probably u should try to extract again opencv 2.4.3 to a temp folder and see what inside.

Comment: I don't understand you have installed but not yet extracted it?
What I do is open the .exe and it will ask where to extract. Just create a temp folder and extract it in it. Then see whether if the .dll files is located thr.

Comment: I'm refering to vc9\bin not vc9\lib folder.

Comment: i have set "..\bin" System path variable, but still shows the same error, is there problem with           Project properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependecies ?

Comment: i have not set "Additional dependecies " under path    Project properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependecies ?

Comment: yes you have to add opencv_core231d.lib
opencv_imgproc231d.lib
opencv_highgui231d.lib
opencv_ml231d.lib
opencv_video231d.lib
opencv_features2d231d.lib
opencv_calib3d231d.lib
opencv_objdetect231d.lib
opencv_contrib231d.lib
opencv_legacy231d.lib
opencv_flann231d.lib change 231 to 243

Comment: i got added, but no good result, will i also have to set this "Additional library directories " under path    Additional library directories ?

Comment: i am now uploading the pics

Comment: everything seems fine to me. One reminder though. Remove everything in release mode. Try debug mode 1st.

Comment: thats great brother, it now runs successfuly, but one problem is that,when it runs and image displays and then it disappear at the moment, and it does not wait for any key to terminate it explicitly

Answer (score 0):

When I use opencv I don't do anything in windows on the first two pictures but I put the paths to the includes in C/C++, General, Additional Include Directories, but I don't know if it makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

In the latest OpenCV 2.8.4 at least.

If you have compiled OpenCV manually, you should compile the Install project as well.
This would effectively create the "install" directory that would contain your

- bin
- include
- libs

like what is found in the normal binary installer package.